# PHP json_decode of nested json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

I have the following code and I want to extract the contents of the items array inside the json file provided bellow btu it gives me an error.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetPlayerItems/v0001?key=7B16ACCC16BB1008FBE73D39587DEF7F&SteamID=76561198069637917.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content,true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach ($json['result'][0]['items'] as $item) {
    $output .="<li>".$item['id']."</li>";
    $output .="<li>".$item['defindex']."</li>";
    $output .="<li>".$item['tradable']."</li>";
    echo $items['items'];
}
$output .="</ul>";

echo $output;
```

Can you please help? Thank you!

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u648734344/public_html/script.php on line 6

Comment: First, post that in your question, not in the comments. Second, how are we supposed to help you when you haven't told us what's in the JSON? Think about what you're posting: is there enough information there for us to help you? Right now, the answer is definitely "no."

Comment: The json file is in the code above, I can not leave the json file because it is over 60000 character long. Thank you but @yuk already fixed it. You are rude.

Comment: Okay, so post an excerpt. Post something. If you read the rules of the site, you would know that you must post enough information *in the question itself* to make the question answerable. I'm not being rude; I am trying to turn your question - which currently falls short of the site's quality standards - into a decent question. You do not seem to be interested in following the site's rules, however, and have responded to constructive criticism with hostilty. Consider this a bit of friendly advice: violating site rules and refusing to accept help will not lead to a good experience for you here.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not follow the rules but I said that the json file is linked bellow in the code. And I only said you are rude. Anyway, thank you for the solution and I will be more careful into the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no item index 'tradable' or 'items' in json data. Also you don't need that [0] there.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_570/GetPlayerItems/v0001?key=7B16ACCC16BB1008FBE73D39587DEF7F&SteamID=76561198069637917.json';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content,true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach ($json['result']['items'] as $item) {
    $output .="<li>".$item['id']."</li>";
    $output .="<li>".$item['defindex']."</li>";
    //$output .="<li>".$item['tradable']."</li>";
    //echo $item['items'];
}
$output .="</ul>";

echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! After 3 hours of trying you fixed it!

Comment: you went to the link?  What if the virus ? :)

Comment: It's a json file from valve, how can you expect a virus? :)